# Access Site Problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, refinerycms, heroku-san

Problem is that sometimes I can't access my site.
I developed my site using Ruby on Rails 3, Refinery CMS and deployed it to heroku.
I bought the domain from domainsite.com.
I can always access my site using the heroku suffix i.e. mysite.herokuapp.com.
I am having sometimes problems when I want to access my site typing mysite.com in address bar. This behaviour is really strange, because after a while without any changes I suddenly can access the site.
And I can't access my site it I use www. prefix. This is the problem I surely like to fix.

Does anyone know where might be the cause of all of this problems?

Comment: Did you follow the setup instruction on Heroku article https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains ?

Comment: Thanks Blue Smith for your answer! The problem was in my domainsite.com configuration. I had to add the A record and point it to the same IP address as the mysite.com

Comment: Glad to know the problem was solved :D

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in my domainsite.com configuration. I had to add the A record and point it to the same IP address as the mysite.com